# How to replace backslashs in URL in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have an URL that looks like:

```
http://example.com/yyy/zzz/something\'s%20List/12/blah=somethingxmore
```

And I need this to redirect to:

```
http://example.com/yyy/zzz/something's+List/12/blah=somethingxmore
```

So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (^(/yyy/zzz/)\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1$2+$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

This allows me to replace the %20 for a plus (+) symbol, but I tried a lot of different rules for the \' replacement with no success.

Comment: Just interested, but how do you have a "\" in an URL?

Comment: This is a client's request. Don't even ask me. I just know that when I hit enter in the browser with that address, the "\" is converted to a "/"

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(yyy/zzz/.*?)\\'s( |\%20)(.*)$ http%3://%1/$1's+$3 [R=301,L,QSA]
```